# Embed a font definition in an emacs theme?

Tags: themes, fonts

As far as I can tell, emacs can only use fonts installed on the operating system.  Is it possible to define a font directly in emacs lisp?  This would allow one to directly embed a font definition in an emacs theme, making the theme more portable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your perception of a font being part of a theme?  It does not necessarily follow that a theme requires a specific font as part of it, in fact I'm pretty sure people would be mad if a theme would do assume a different font than they have customized Emacs to use.

Comment: @wasamasa not necessarily. Some times I need to copy my setup to another machine, and then my fvorite theme as well as some other settings come out botched because I forgot to install the font I need. I would be, too interested in finding some mechanism for Emacs to load fonts not necessarily installed in the system / install the fonts with the theme.

Comment: @wasamasa You are correct that "it does not necessarily follow that a theme requires a specific font".  However, a theme can specify a font.  The relationship between a font and a theme is less important to me than whether Emacs has a way to load fonts not necessarily installed in the system.

Comment: Even with the fact that one can specify a font family, pretty much anything is using a generic specifier such as `Sans`, `Serif` or `Monospace`, the font stack on the system will pick the right font automatically based on that.

Comment: @wasamasa The font family referenced in the theme I am creating is a specific font that is not likely to be installed.  Generic specifiers won't do what I want here.

Comment: Such specific configurations do not belong into a theme anyways as they are highly subjective and rather a customization one does in his Emacs configuration.  In other words, while I find the question interesting, I suspect this is the wrong way to solve deployment woes. On Linux machines it's sufficient to just copy the font file to `~/.local/share/fonts` for the desired effect.